# models.set_weights() gives None

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to build an ensamble DNN model. I train e.g. 5 models, take the weights and average them. After that I wanted to clone a first model and assign the new weights. But it does not work.

The Model is built like this:

```
 def build_DNN_model(self):
        # initialize the DNN
        ann = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
        # add first hidden layer
        num_neurons = self.num_neurons
        ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=num_neurons, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(1.)))
        ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
        # add second hidden layer
        ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=num_neurons, activation='relu'))
        ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
        # add output layer
        ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1))
        # compile
        ann.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
        return ann
```

Then the model is fitted to the data, actually I do 5 models, and fit all of them to the same data.

After that I create a list of KerasModel Objects, called "members".

And now I would like to assign my new weights to a clone of one of the models. But even if I do that:

```
members[0].set_weights(members[0].get_weights())
```

it returns me None.

I use Tensoflow 2 version.

I would appreciate your help very much.

Comment: You mean set_weights is returning None? That is correct, the set_weights function does not return anything.

Comment: But how can I get a model with the updated weights, if model.set_weights(weights) returns me None?

Comment: There is no need to return anything, set_weights operates on the model instance you call it on.

Comment: I think your whole question is based on the faulty assumption that set_weights has to return a Model instance, where did you get this idea from? Its not how the function works and it is not documented as such.

Comment: I are right, it looks so. The idea is from here: https://machinelearningmastery.com/polyak-neural-network-model-weight-ensemble/?unapproved=560633&moderation-hash=0aa6516b20a42c8186e8b1af6a9bd2b7#comment-560633. The have found out that problem is in the comile step in the function model_weight_ensemble. I do regression. After compilation the model turns to None

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define the input shape in your first layer of the model

after doing this I simply create 2 models like yours (m1,m2) and assign to m2 the same weights to m1... they are the same

```
def build_DNN_model(input_dim):
  # initialize the DNN
  ann = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
  # add first hidden layer
  num_neurons = 32
  ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=num_neurons, activation='relu', 
                                kernel_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(1.),
                                input_dim=input_dim))
  ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
  # add second hidden layer
  ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=num_neurons, activation='relu'))
  ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
  # add output layer
  ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1))
  # compile
  ann.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
  return ann 

m1 = build_DNN_model((100))
m2 = build_DNN_model((100))

m2.set_weights(m1.get_weights())

# check the weights
[(w1==w2).all() for w1,w2 in zip(m1.get_weights(),m2.get_weights())]
# [True, True, True, True, True, True]
```

[the notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1gnx7_nt_miGLtJv1jo1CF1mHaL89ceCW?usp=sharing)

**EDIT1**: assign random weights to m1:

```
m1.set_weights([np.random.uniform(0,1, i.shape) for i in m1.get_weights()])
```

**EDIT2**: [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1dKGztlS4p8SO-7izGQK55zTemOUhb10K?usp=sharing) you find the working implementation of `model_weight_ensemble` in your contest from https://machinelearningmastery.com/polyak-neural-network-model-weight-ensemble/

Answer (score 1):

**Creating a simple model:**

```
def create_model1():
        model = tf.keras.Sequential()
        model.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=(13,)))
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 6, activation='relu', name = 'd1'))
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 2, activation='softmax', name = 'd2'))
        return model
```

**Model Architecture:**

[image: this]

**Looking at layers:**

```
model.layers
```

**Ouput:**

```
[<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense at 0x2193acc95c8>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense at 0x2193ad3ad08>]
```

**Looking at the weights of 2nd dense layer:**

```
model.layers[1].weights
```

**Output:**

```
[<tf.Variable 'd2/kernel:0' shape=(6, 2) dtype=float32, numpy=
 array([[ 0.11061734,  0.61788374],
        [ 0.31208295,  0.19295567],
        [-0.6812483 ,  0.05383837],
        [ 0.39284903,  0.69312006],
        [-0.519426  ,  0.67820543],
        [-0.7337165 ,  0.11025453]], dtype=float32)>,
 <tf.Variable 'd2/bias:0' shape=(2,) dtype=float32, numpy=array([0., 0.], dtype=float32)>]
```

**Setting weights:**

```
new_weights = [tf.random.uniform(shape = (6,2)), tf.random.uniform(shape = (2,))]
model.layers[1].set_weights(new_weights)
```

For setting weights the shape of new_weights should match the shape of weights of that particular layer.

Here, new_weights is a list containing two values. 1st element is the weight of the kernel and 2nd element is the weight for bias.

Comment: Dear Aniket, thank for your input. I did all the layers together. The shapes were the same.

Comment: Add the output of print(members[0]) in your question.